# Import a self-signed certificate onto my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ssl

I am developing an app that uses SSL to communicate with my server.

The connection keeps failing with `The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be (removed.com) which could put your confidential information at risk.`

I've tried emailing the certificate to myself and importing it on my iphone, but the error still occurs.

Even visiting the webpage through safari, it warns me and asks if I want to accept the certificate.

How can I just get my iphone to ignore the invalid certificate? It's really annoying!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are describing sounds like a wrong configuration of your server certificate. Are you sure, that the certificate is not expired, matches the domain (or subdomain) and is valid.

For a quick try and for development purposes you could use the following workaround for UIWebView and standard connections. (**Attention**: This will be rejected from App Store):

```
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];
```

If you can specify the type of connection you are using or post some code we could possibly find a way to disable the SSL verification.